# Best-practice: bundling tomcat and configuring SSL with a keystore

Tags: tomcat, ssl, installation, keystore, advanced-installer

I'm working on the installer for a product which requires installation of tomcat 7 and configuring it for SSL.  We want to generate a self-signed certificate (have installation dialogs to get the required user input) and then update the tomcat configuration with the location and password for the keystore.

In my mind, the straight forward (which is often not the best) way to do this is to build the required .xml files by having a custom action run a batch file.

Is there a better or more standard way to do this?

Comment: Hey Bro, I've asked one question here and it looks like whatever I am trying to do, that you have already done. Can you please take a look at this question and do help me if you can, thanks in advance. :)
Question URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949030/steps-to-deploy-web-application-on-tomcat-via-install4j-installer-or-advanced-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced Installer has a [built-in support to update the content of XML files at install time](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-import-edit-xml-file.html). You **don't** need to write any custom actions. Check the example I linked above and see if you can adapt it to fit your scenario, ping me if you have any questions.